# How to inject JQuery into existing page within a UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to inject JQuery into a `UIWebView` of a page that I can't control, say Google, for example.  When a `UITextField` gets focus, I am executing the following lines of code:

```
NSString* scriptInject = @"var headElement = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; var script = document.createElement('script'); 
    script.setAttribute('src','http://jquery.com/src/jquery-latest.js');
    script.setAttribute('type','text/javascript'); headElement.appendChild(script);";
    [myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:scriptInject];    
    [myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"$(document).ready(function() {$('body').css('background', '#FF0000');}"];
```

I am executing the background change to validate that I am able to run a JQuery script.  I can verify that the Objective-C method is being called, and I even planted an `alert` for the onload of the newly created `<script>` tag, so I know that it is being executed in the `UIWebView`.  How do I inject it correctly that I can execute it?

EDIT:

I have event tried this after calling the function to change the color:

```
[myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"alert($('body').css());"];
```

No alert shows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If jQuery is not in the DOM already you can use `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` to inject it. I've had similar problem, I wrote a blog post about it: [HTML parsing/screen scraping in iOS](http://benedictcohen.co.uk/2010/08/24/html-parsingscreen-scraping-with-uiwebview/).

Comment: I find that my code does indeed work, just not reliably.  After reading your article, it may be because the DOM is not yet ready.  After skimming over your article, performing a delayed selector may be the trick for waiting to execute the change using jQuery until the DOM is ready.  I'll give it a try when I get a chance.

Comment: your blogpost disappeared from the web :(

Comment: @Hamutsi. Fixed! I changed blog engine and broke all my links.

Comment: your blog has again disappeared, guess this is why SO always want you to copy code into answers

Comment: Your blog is gone again; post the answer here instead :)  no one can see the solution now

Answer (score 7):

This has worked for me:

```
NSString *jqueryCDN = @"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js";
NSData *jquery = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:jqueryCDN]];
NSString *jqueryString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:jquery encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jqueryString];

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:/*jquery commands here*/];
```

Taken from [this article](http://www.altinkonline.nl/tutorials/xcode/uiwebview/load-jquery-in-uiwebview/).

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but both this code and the code in the source article make poor use of dataWithContentsOfURL:. The jQuery library ends up being downloaded from googleapis.com while blocking the main thread.

Comment: Agreed! This answer is here for demonstration purposes only, this isn't the recommended approach, of course.

Comment: when should i implement "stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString"? didFinish?