# Inject Jquery into site within an IOS Webview

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I'm attempting to inject jQuery into a site that's not mine, and is in an iOS webview. I'd like to change a few things like the background color, font, etc.

I read the answers here...
[How to inject JQuery into existing page within a UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527317/how-to-inject-jquery-into-existing-page-within-a-uiwebview)

But couldn't figure out a way to do it.

All the solutions I've read suggest using stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString to inject jQuery. I believe this solution only injects JavaScript though, while I think what might work is how jQuery is normally installed with the html head tag inside a script tag like this

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js">
    </script>
</head>
```

I don't know how to inject that though? Or maybe there's a different way entirely?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573076/how-to-inject-jquery-to-any-webpage and executejavascript in the webview with that JS code

Comment: thanks @UXDart I saw that one, but assumed it wasn't an IOS webview solution, if you know something that would work in IOS please let me know!